# How can I extract the text next to an image with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, getelementsbyclassname, getelementsbytagname, parent-node

Here's the challenge:

[image: Code Excerpt]

We have an image and text that describes it all nested in the same div. When somebody clicks on that image, we want Google Tag Manager to return that text.

Basically, we need to:

1. Go up 3 parent nodes
2. Go down to the child node with the class "right-section"
3. Go down to the child node with the class "is-title"
4. Go down to the child node with the tag "a"
5. Extract the text

Using my crude, self-taught Javascript knowledge, I came up with this monstrosity of a function:

```
function(){
  return el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("right-section")[0].getElementsByClassName("is-title")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerText;
}
```

... which does not work at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: imgur is blocked in our country thats why it dosent show up btw are you allowed to use dom functions like querySelector ? its very easy if you use dom functions

Comment: I see, thanks. Here's the relevant code:

<div class="is-search-sections">
 <div class="left-section">
         <div class="thumbnail">
                 <a href="USERS CLICK HERE"><img src="_"></a>
                 </div>
        </div>
 <div class="right-section">
  <div class="is-title">
                        <a href="https://tempgtm4stg.wpengine.com/resources/existing_service_rate_request_form/">
                                                                TARGET TEXT

Comment: Never post code or errors as images, and it belongs in your question, not down here. See [ask].

Comment: This is one of many results in a listing using the same classes, so while document.querySelector(".is-title").innerText returns text, it does not return the text connected to the specific image the user clicked on.

Comment: When you run your functions what errors are there on the browser's dev tools console, and how/where is el defined?

Comment: el = {{Click Element}} as defined by Google Tag Manager. There are no errors in the console, but this returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ultimately worked, for anyone Googling this:

```
function (){
     el = {{Click Element}};
     var item = el.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerText;
     return item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an example markup basically the idea is use `closest` function to go up to dom tree and then use 'querySelector' with that result to go down to any element inside it

```js
const img = document.querySelector(".item_image")
img.onclick = e=>{
    const root = e.target.closest(".card") // goind back to root element
    const text = root.querySelector(".text") // going down to text element
    console.log(text.innerText)
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width:400px;">
    <div class="sections">
        <img class="item_image" style="width:200px;" src="https://2.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~C1000x0S4000x4000T1200x1200~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="another-seci">
        <div class="text">
            Despite its modest MSRP, Fujifilm's entry-level X-A3 has dual control dials, a tilting touchscreen, and the same 24MP sensor from the company's flagship models - but with a traditional Bayer color filter array instead of X-Trans. We're pushing through our full 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this isn't quite there yet.

Some of these functions aren't possible in GTM. I can get it running like this:

function() {
    var el = {{Click Element}}
    var root = el.target.closest(".is-search-sections") // goind back to root element
    var text = root.querySelector(".is-title") // going down to text element
    return text.innerText
}

But it returns the text for the first item in the list regardless of where the user clicks.

Comment: obviously i just showed the basic with single element and it is working as required now you can make your own functions with them however you wanted to and if possible use this functions and avoid full custom code for going to parentNode one by one it will break with any future change in dom

Answer (score 1):

ok, Here is an example of what you need to do. If you need an exact answer that would work by just copy pasting it, show the block of HTML exactly how Amir did. I used Amir's HTML example to do the trick. Also, if you see that it takes the same text when you click on different images, include in your html snippet the code from other images, so that we could see how they relate to the parents and could refine the selectors.

Here's your CJS code:

```
function(){
  return {{Click Element}}.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".text").innerText
}
```

There's completely no need to hop from node to node once you got to the bottom. From the bottom parentElement, just do the query selector once and you're in good hands.

You could also use .closest, but it seems like its complexity is way over just a few parentElements. I know it's insignificant, but hey.

Here is how I debug it right on this page (in Amir's answer): [image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item_image').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        const root = event.target.closest(".card") // goind back to root element
    const text = root.querySelector(".text") // going down to text element
    console.log(text.innerText)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width:400px;">
    <div class="sections">
        <img class="item_image" style="width:200px;" src="https://2.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~C1000x0S4000x4000T1200x1200~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="another-seci">
        <div class="text">
            Despite its modest MSRP, Fujifilm's entry-level X-A3 has dual control dials, a tilting touchscreen, and the same 24MP sensor from the company's flagship models - but with a traditional Bayer color filter array instead of X-Trans. We're pushing through our full 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card" style="width:400px;">
    <div class="sections">
        <img class="item_image" style="width:200px;" src="https://2.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~C1000x0S4000x4000T1200x1200~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="another-section">
        <div class="text">
            BlaDespite its modest MSRP, Fujifilm's entry-level X-A3 has dual control dials, a tilting touchscreen, and the same 24MP sensor from the company's flagship models - but with a traditional Bayer color filter array instead of X-Trans. We're pushing through our full 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to query all ".card"'s and add listeners to each. I modified the code accordingly

Comment: You can edit your own answer, you don't need to comment on it.

Comment: updated my answer to satisfy this html. You just had to remove on parentElement. Try it out.